# How to make 10 requests/second API calls to avoid external API rate limit using Java?

Tags: java, api, rate-limiting, http-status-code-429

I am making third party GET API calls which has per second 10 requests rate limit .How can successfully control http GET requests to avoid hitting rate limits of third party. I am using Vertx Webclient for making GET request.

Answer (score 0):

two ways to do it with CompletableFutures:

1. fire off 10 `CompletableFuture`s that make your requests then send the thread to sleep for 1s - see `runAsync()` and `supplyAsync()` methods.
2. execute 1 `CompletableFuture` and sleep 1/10th of a second.

If you store the CompletableFutures in a list/map (whatever works for your situation best) you can then `.get()` the answers later when you need to access the results.

Comment: you mean the main thread? Spin off a new one then so the main one doesn't need to sleep?